# When emacs locks up

Tags: emacs, slime

Is there any keystroke combination that shuts down a process in emacs? Occasionally I make a newbie mistake at the Common Lisp REPL and my Emacs locks up. On Mac I just force-quit because I can't find a way to get control of Emacs back. But I'd prefer not close Emacs if I can avoid it.

Comment: In certain cases, a `kill` or `killall` command aimed at the process doing the blocking can work wonders. No keystroke that I know of though.

Comment: If you are in an infinite loop you should be able to hit Ctrl-G to get out of it.

Comment: @cobbal but I'd need to be able to actually run M-x to type `kill` right? When it's locked, I can't seem to do anything.

Comment: @OpenLearner I meant from a command line. For instance if you're using sbcl, the command `killall sbcl` will probably get emacs going again. It will also kill everything other sbcl program you're running, so think before using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Try `C-g` (`keyboard-quit`). Try repeating it multiple times.
2. Try `C-]` (`abort-recursive-edit`). Try repeating it multiple times.
3. Try `ESC ESC ESC` (`keyboard-escape-quit`). Try repeating it multiple times.
4. Give up and kill the process.

Comment: in step 4, specifically:  `pkill -SIGUSR2 -i emacs`  which will force emacs into debug mode, you can then try to debug (!) or just type q to quit that and then restart emacs cleanly.

I have a shell alias   `pokemacs='pkill -SIGUSR2 -i emacs'` because it's happening a lot on my Macintosh/Spacemacs

Comment: `Activity Monitor > View > Send Signal to Process… > User Defined 2 (SIGUSR2) > Send` should drop a runaway Emacs into the debugger after you select the Emacs process in `/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app`